# Distinguishing "politics" from "policy" in the same sentence

Tags: traducción, ambigüedad, desambiguación

There's an earlier discussion on "politics" versus "policy" in Spanish,

["Domestic politics" and "domestic policy" in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30772/domestic-politics-and-domestic-policy-in-spanish)

both of which are "política". Various strategies were offered to make "policy" clear: use the plural, qualifiers like "política económica" etc.

But what if you want to say something like "That's a question of politics, not policy"? This would seem to call for "política" twice. I just wonder if there's a concise way to signal the distinction.

Comment: No parece haber distinción en el idioma: véase [‘Politics’ frente a ‘policy’](https://elpais.com/economia/2015/09/11/actualidad/1441970769_266935.html) o [esta otra](https://nadaesgratis.es/garicano/“policy”-y-“politics”-una-distincion-inexistente-en-nuestro-idioma-pero-muy-necesaria)

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic difference between 'politics' and 'policy' in English is that the first is a non-count noun and the second a count noun, whereas in Spanish 'política' is used in both ways. In the example you give, I would use words like 'general' and 'específico' or 'concreto' to make the distinction. The next sentence could work as a translation:

Es una cuestión de política en general, no de políticas concretas.

You can substitute 'específicas' or 'particulares' for 'concretas' and 'más que de' for 'no de', with the same meaning.